Something breaks updating an active WooCommerce Subscription manually
I'm using the WooCommerce Subscription official plugin on a migrated e-commerce.
After the migration some of the data resulted to be inconsistent, mainly, I think, due to this coupon data structure update for the Orders:
https://developer.woocommerce.com/2024/02/08/changes-in-order-coupons-line-item-storage/
I was getting the wrong  values for the product in the Subscription and Order objects. The coupon was applied in a strange manner and the the discount was being computed only in the gray part of the Item section, while, in the whiter part, the cost was being displayed without discount.
After trying to to some updates with the Woocommerce API, I took the path of the manual update, and I updated 30 Subscriptions objects, hoping that the automatically generated relative Orders would result to be correct and consistent.
I'm still waiting for the renewals, but what I see now in each manually updated Subscription is the Related Orders at the bottom are not displaying and an error is showing:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function update_meta_data() on bool in /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wcs-meta-box-related-orders.php:102 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): WCS_Meta_Box_Related_Orders::output_rows() 
#1 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters() 
#2 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() 
#3 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-related-orders-table.php(49): do_action() 
#4 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wcs-meta-box-related-orders.php(31): include_once('...') 
#5 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/template.php(1456): WCS_Meta_Box_Related_Orders::output() 
#6 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php(723): do_meta_boxes() 
#7 /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/post.php(206): require('...') 
#8 {main} thrown in /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wcs-meta-box-related-orders.php on line 102

There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

If I click on the (green marked) Parent Order, I'm able to see all the Order stack, but something is broken in the Subscription object.
Does anybody have an idea of what is happening?

This question is related to a data migration issue, so the only way to solve it, is by the migration software used for it. You should also try to contact WooCommerce or/and WooCommerce Subscriptions support, as this can be a bug. Note that stack overflow doesn't handle any software support.
